# Verifying a solution to a Differential Equation 2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integration

How can I verify if this function is a solution of the
differential equation?

$ y' - 2ty = 1;$

$y = e^{t^2}\int_{0}^te^{-s^2}ds+ e^{t^2}$

I'm stuck, so any tip will be helpful

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know what it means for a function to be a solution of a differential equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** You need to differentiate and plug in. Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Note that the derivative of
$$\int_0^t e^{-s^2}\,ds$$
with respect to $t$ is $e^{-t^2}$.

Comment: Hi André what exactly you did to solve the integral, variable change or something special?

Comment: I did not solve the integral, I used the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Roughly speaking, it says that if $f(s)$ is a reasonable function, say continuous, and $F(t)=\int_a^t f(s)\,ds$, then $F'(t)=f(t)$. No need to integrate and then differentiate! Good thing, since $e^{-s^2}$ does not have an elementary antiderivative. For more detail, look up Fundamental Theorem of Calculus in Wikipedia, or in almost any calculus book.

Answer (score 1):

You might also remember the following formula and then decide if it's a solution or not:
$$y=e^{-\int P(x)dx}\int e^{\int P(x)dx}f(x)+ce^{-\int P(x)dx}$$ where $$y'(x)+P(x)y(x)=f(x)$$